# Laravel Livewire: Fpdi error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%', "%PDF-1.5"

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire, fpdi

In the application, we're trying to implement the fpdi to able to export the pdf that has a templated but it gives us an error

[image]

The versions of the ff

Laravel: 8.83.27

setasign/fpdf: "1.8",

setasign/fpdi: "^2.6",

Livewire component

```
<button wire:loading.remove wire:click.prevent='export' class="btn btn-warning text-white me-2">
                                <i class="bi bi-download"></i>
                                <span class='btn-text'>Export</span>
                           </button>
```

Controller

```
    public static function export($data)
{
    $period_month                                   = date('n', strtotime($data['direct_payment']->date));
    $get_year                                       = date('Y', strtotime($data['direct_payment']->date));
    $previos_quarter_month                          =  Bir2307DateController::CheckBirPreviousMonth($period_month);
    $period_from                                    = date($previos_quarter_month.'01'.$get_year);
    $last_quarter_month                             = app(Bir2307DateController::class)->CheckBirLastQuartMonth($period_month);
    $last_day                                       = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $last_quarter_month,strtotime('Y'));
    $period_to                                      = date($last_quarter_month.$last_day.$get_year);
    // $period_to               = date('mtY', strtotime($data['payments_others']->payment_date));
    $period_from_split                              = str_split($period_from);
    $period_to_split                                = str_split($period_to);
    $vendor_tin                                     = str_split($data['direct_payment']->vendorCustomer->tin);
    $vendor_zip_code                                = str_split($data['direct_payment']->vendorCustomer->address_zip_code);
    $vendor_address                                 = $data['direct_payment']->vendorCustomer->address_street.", ".$data['direct_payment']->vendorCustomer->address_city.", ".$data['direct_payment']->vendorCustomer->address_province;
    $company_tin                                    = str_split($data['company']->tin);
    $company_zip_code                               = ($data['company']->zip_code) ? str_split($data['company']->zip_code) : str_split("0000");
    $company_address                                = $data['company']->street." ".$data['company']->brgy.", ".$data['company']->city.", ".$data['company']->province;

    // $authorized_representative                       = static::getAuthorizedRepresentativeLength($data['company']->authorized_representative);
    // $authorized_representative_position_tin      = ($data['company']->authorized_representative_position_tin) ? '('.$data['company']->authorized_representative_position_tin.')' : '';


    $pdf = new Fpdi();
    $page_count = $pdf->setSourceFile(public_path()."/bir-form/bir-2307.pdf");
    for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $page_count; $pageNo++) {
        $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplIdx);
        $width = $size["width"];
        $height = $size["height"];
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 5, 5, 205,280);
        // $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 5, 5, 205);
        // $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 5, 5, $width,$height);
        /* ==================== FOR THE PERIOD FROM ==================== */
        if($pageNo == 1)
        {
            $pdf->SetFont('Times');
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
            $pdf->SetFontSize(10);
            $pdf->Text(57,41, $period_from_split[0]);
            $pdf->Text(61,41, $period_from_split[1]);
            $pdf->Text(66,41, $period_from_split[2]);
            $pdf->Text(70,41, $period_from_split[3]);
            $pdf->Text(74.5,41, $period_from_split[4]);
            $pdf->Text(79,41, $period_from_split[5]);
            $pdf->Text(83.5,41, $period_from_split[6]);
            $pdf->Text(87.5,41, $period_from_split[7]);
            
            
        }
         
    }

    return $pdf->Output('I','direct_payment.pdf');
}
```

Question: how to able to export using FPDI?

Comment: Your PHP script is returning the contents of a PDF file and your script is trying to parse it as JSON. I can't say more since you didn't include any of the script.

Comment: What script you are referring to? the js files that included in the projects?

Comment: The script that is triggering the error message in your console.

Comment: i dont have any script, are you familiar with the livewire?

Comment: Then you're returning a different content than the livewire script expects. From the error message, it's clearly trying to parse it as JSON.

Comment: But I followed the documentation of FPDI. Above is all of my snippet

Comment: I'm sure that's the correct method to get a user to download a PDF, but you're not asking the user to download it, you're asking the browser to download it with ajax request.

Comment: You are suggesting that I make it jquery/javascript?

Comment: I think what you want is a simple link.